# Unable to generate a multiplication table with user input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page which prompts the user to enter a positive integer from 1 to 9, then the javascript code will generate a multiplication table from the input value all the way to 9. I am getting an error in which I cannot retrieve the value and do a multiplication with it.

```js
function timesTable()
{
    var values = document.getElementById('value1');

    var showTables = '';
    for (var i=1; i<9; i++) {
       showTables += values + " x " + i +" = "+ values*i + "\n";
    }
    var p_tables = document.getElementById('tables').innerHTML = showTables;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter an integer from 1 to 9 : </label>
<input type="text" size=20 id=value1 name="value">
<button onclick="timesTable()">Generate times table</button><br> <br>
<p id="tables"></p>
```

Expected result: 
[image: expectedresult]

Comment: change: `showTabels += values ` to `showTables += values.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take the value of the element not the element itself

```
 var values = document.getElementById('value1').value;
```

```js
function timesTable()
{
    var values = document.getElementById('value1').value;

    var showTables = '';
    for (var i=1; i<9; i++) {
       showTables += values + " x " + i +" = "+ values*i + "<br>";
    }
    var p_tables = document.getElementById('tables').innerHTML = showTables;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter an integer from 1 to 9 : </label>
<input type="text" size=20 id=value1 name="value">
<button onclick="timesTable()">Generate times table</button><br> <br>
<p id="tables"></p>
```

Comment: If it helped you upvote and mark it as correct so it can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply the element itself. What you actually want is the value.

```js
function timesTable()
{
    var values = document.getElementById('value1').value;

    var showTables = '';
    for (var i=1; i<9; i++) {
       showTables += values + " x " + i +" = "+ values*i + "\n";
    }
    var p_tables = document.getElementById('tables').innerHTML = showTables;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter an integer from 1 to 9 : </label>
<input type="text" size=20 id=value1 name="value">
<button onclick="timesTable()">Generate times table</button><br> <br>
<p id="tables"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

the javascript line in which you are trying to find value, is wrong as it will return the whole DOM and it's attributes and property.
You just have to find it's value, replace you line

```
var values = document.getElementById('value1');
```

with

```
var values = document.getElementById('value1').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want.
Note that if the user enters something unexpected, it may still fail. You can use an input of [type="number"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp) to require an integer (at least in some browsers.)

```
  const userValue = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  const p_tables = document.getElementById("tables");
  let outputHtml = "";
  for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    outputHtml += userValue + " x " + i + " = " + userValue * i + "<br/>";
  }
  p_tables.innerHTML = outputHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using input field as text for table generation its better to use Number as input type and to get the value of input field you have to use **value** function as used in above code and for line break use
**<\br>**(please ignore '\').

```js
function timesTable()
{
    var values = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    var showTables = '';
    for (var i=1; i<=9; i++) {
       showTables += values + " x " + i +" = "+ values*i + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById('tables').innerHTML = showTables;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter an integer from 1 to 9 : </label>
<input type="Number" size=20 id=value1 name="value">
<button onclick="timesTable()">Generate times table</button><br> <br>
<p id="tables"></p>
```